# Best way to get minutes with from to hours?

Tags: php

I have for example:

```
$hours = "10:11 - 13:34";
```

How is the best way for get minutes with this string? I would most like to have them in the array, for example

```
$results = array(11, 34);
```

Then can also be:

```
$hours = "7:10 - 22:00";
$hours = "07:55-14:15";
$hours = "07:55 -14:15";
```

etc...

I can:

```
$expl = explode('-', trim($hours));
```

and next explode by ":", but maybe is better way?

Comment: Do it regexp-way Use https://regex101.com/ for build (study) regular expressions an code generating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think preg_match_all is what you need

```
$a = "7:10 - 22:00";

preg_match_all("/[0-9]+:(?P<minutes>[0-9]+)/", $a, $matches);

$minutes = array_map(
    function($i) {
        return intval($i);
    },
    $matches["minutes"]
);

var_dump($minutes);
```

the output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(10)
  [1]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's `DateTime` class to manipulate dates and times, rather than using string manipulation.

```
$time = '10:11';
$minutes = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time)->format('i');
echo $minutes; // 11
```

So for your example:

```
$hours = "10:11 - 13:34";

// Extract times from string
list($time1, $time2) = explode('-', $hours);

// Remove white-space
$time1 = trim($time1);
$time2 = trim($time2);

// Format as minutes, and add into an array
$result = [
    DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time1)->format('i'),
    DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time2)->format('i'),
];

print_r($result);
```

=

```
Array
(
    [0] => 11
    [1] => 34
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of strtotime! It's really powerful

```
<?php

function getMinuteFromTimes($time){
    //strip all white not just spaces
    $tmp = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $time);
    //explode the time
    $tmp = explode ('-',$tmp);
    //make our return array
    $return = array();
    //loop our temp array
    foreach($tmp as $t){
        //add our minutes to the new array
        $return[] = date('i',strtotime($t));
    }

    //return the array
    return $return;

}

print_r(getMinuteFromTimes("7:10 - 22:00"));
echo '</br>';
print_r(getMinuteFromTimes("07:55-14:15"));
echo '</br>';
print_r(getMinuteFromTimes("07:55 -14:15"));
?>
```

Output:
`Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 00 )

Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 15 )

Array ( [0] => 55 [1] => 15 )`
This function will also accept inputs like: "12:00-13:13- 15:12" or single inputs.